# How to track order in ordered list that has one looping list item fed different parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm populating a list of YouTube videos. I want the list to be ordered by number. The thing is, my ordered list only has one list item. That item is looped through with Jquery.each and is given a different value with each iteration.

The way it is coded in my example below, every list item listed as number 1.

```
$.each(results, function(index,value) {
        html += '<ol><li><a data-video-  type="https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + value.id.videoId + '?autoplay=1">     <img src="'  +value.snippet.thumbnails.medium.url +  '">' +    value.snippet.title + '</a>)</li><ol>';        });
        $('#results').html(html);
```

Comment: Why dont you sort results before put them in to the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can short your results before adding to `ol`. Then you can add like following:

```
html = "<ol>";
$.each(results, function(index,value) {
    html += '<li><a data-video-  type="https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + value.id.videoId + '?autoplay=1">     <img src="'  +value.snippet.thumbnails.medium.url +  '">' +    value.snippet.title + '</a>)</li>';        
});
html += "</ol>";
$('#results').html(html);
```

Comment: This should have been obvious to me. Thanks. Nice solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your code. Append each list to `ul`.

```
 $.each(results, function (i) {
   $('<li>').appendTo('.orderedList'); //Class of `ul`
 }
```